# Using function on another function

Tags: matlab, function

I have the following working function (a). This function is responsible to solve error within another function.

```
function [a] = algorithm1(z)
if (z==0)
    j=1;
    a=j;
    disp('Your computer is switch on from state offline')
elseif (z==1)
    j=1;
    a=j;
    disp('Your computer is working properly')
elseif (z==2)
    %j=2;  Value 2 for status of rebooting
    disp('Your computer is rebooting')
    j=1;
    a=j;
    disp('Your computer is working properly after rebooting')
else
    disp('unidentified error')
end

end
```

My problem is how to make another `function(b)` that will take the `function(a)` above as its solution. I was hoping it would come out like this

```
T=100 status 1, your computer is working properly
T=101 status 1, your computer is working properly
T=102 status 2, your computer is working properly after rebooting
.
.
.
T=200 status 1, your computer is working properly
```

The T is a looping function and the status function(b) is generated randomly. How can I give function (a) to function (b) so that it will continously solve error using function (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a function to another function you need to use a function handle to [an anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

The general syntax looks like this:

```
handle = @(input1, input2)function_to_call(input1, other_input, input2)
```

In your case, you could write function `b` like this

```
function b(afunction)
    for k = 1:100
        afunction(randi([1 2]));
    end
end
```

Then call `b` passing it a handle to `a`.

```
afunction = @(z)a(z);
% or just: afunction = @a

b(afunction)
```

Alternately, if both `a` and `b` are on your path, you can simply call `a` directly from `b`.

```
function b()
    for k = 1:100
        a(randi([1 2]));
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but I'll be pedantic because I see the terms mis-used all of the time: an anonymous function is not "also called a function handle." The link indicates the, perhaps subtle, difference. I like to think of the two in the same way as a pointer and a memory address.

Comment: @horchler I agree that it's a subtle but important distinction. I'll update it. How do you think it would be worded best?